# Matlab, Sum Function for a Matrix row

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

Basically the sum function calculate the sum of the columns, that is to say if we have a 4x4 matrix we would get a 1X4 vector

> A = magic(4)
>
> A =

```
16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1
```

> sum(A)
>
> ans =

```
34    34    34    34
```

But if I want to get the Summation of the rows then i have 2 methods, the first is to get the transpose of the matrix then get the summation of the transposed matrix,and finally get the transpose of the result...., The Second method is to use dimension argument for the Sum function "sum(A, 2)"

> > A = magic(4)
>
> A =

```
16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1
```

> sum(A,2)
>
> ans =

```
34
34
34
34
```

The problem is here I cannot understand how this is done, If anyone could please tell me the idea/concept behind this method,

Comment: What? What do you mean by concept? You do understand what a sum is, right?

Comment: I would like to know how the function works from inside, the math it depends on.

Comment: What do you mean? If `dim = 1`, then it sums the columns and returns a row vector. If `dim = 2`, then it sums the rows and returns a column vector. What it is exactly that is tripping you up?

Comment: what tripp me is i cannot understand how sum(A,1) gives columns and sum(A,2) gives row Summation , what is the code inside this function that makes this difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly how `sum` internally works, but we can guess it does something similar to this.

Matlab stores matrices (or *N*-dimensional arrays) in memory using [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). This means the order for the elements in memory for a 3 x 4 matrix is

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8 11
3 6 9 12
```

So it first stores element (1,1), then (1,2), then (13), then (2,1), ...

In fact, this is the order you use when you apply [linear indexing](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) (that is, index a matrix with a single number). For example, let

```
A = [7 8 6 2
     9 0 3 5
     6 3 2 1];
```

Then `A(4)` gives `8`.

With this in mind, it's easy to guess that what `sum(A,1)` does is traverse elements consecutively: A(1)+A(2)+A(3) to obtain the sum of the first column, then A(4)+A(5)+A(6) to sum the second column, etc. In contrast, `sum(A,2)` proceeds in steps of `size(A,1)` (3 in this example): A(1)+A(4)+A(7)+A(10) to compute the sum of the first row, etc.

As a side note, this is probably related with the observed fact that `sum(A,1)` is faster than `sum(A,2)`.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about the concept of linear indexing and how matlab stores data, when the question poped up i began to think about an algorithm with loop and conditions to find the answer, but what you proposed here is totally logical, thanks again

Comment: @A.Fahim Glad I could help. I wasn't sure if this kind of explanation was what you were after

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you are asking. `sum` takes two inputs, the first of which is a multidimensional array `A`, say.

Now let's take `sA = size(A)`, and `d` between 1 and `ndims(A)`.
To understand what `B = sum(A,d)` does, first we find out what the size of `B` is.
That's easy, `sB = sA; sB(d) = 1;`. So in a way, it will "reduce" the size of `A` along dimension `d`.

The rest is trivial: every element in `B` is the sum of elements in `A` along dimension `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `sum(A) = sum(A,1)` which outputs the sum of the columns in the matrix. `1` indicates the columns. So, `sum(A,2)` outputs the sum of the rows in the matrix. `2` indicating the rows. More than that, the sum command will output the entire matrix because there is only `2` dimensions (rows and columns)

Comment: `sum(A)` is not sum along first dimension (columns). It's sum along first _non-singleton_ dimension. Try `sum([1 2 3])` (row vector)

Comment: Yup, for the case above, the first non-singleton dimension is the columns.

Comment: Thanks but what has the function done to reach this, the concept of the algorithm that made the function gives me the summation of the columns @ Sum(A,1) and the summation of the rows @ sum(A,2).